# Submit button doesn't work in bootstrap btn-group class

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, button

Could you please advise how to implement the bootstrap btn-group element which consists of one submit button and the rest of buttons work as checkboxes. Actually I've created the mentioned but my submit button doesn't work and when it is pressed, nothing happens.
Here is what I have now:

```
<form class="form-group" action ="" method = "get" novalidate>
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_tag" value="2" id="id_select_tag_0" /> Mysql
    </label >
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_tag" value="3" id="id_select_tag_1" /> Disk health
    </label2>       
</div>
</form>
```

[And the block looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbD8z.png)

If I put submit button out of the btn-group block it works:

```
<form class="form-group" action ="" method = "get" novalidate>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
...
```

[However, it looks ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mq1K.png)

So is it possible to have a lot of buttons work as checkboxes and one which work as submit in one bootstrap button group?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with javascript :

```
<form class="form-group" action ="" method = "get" novalidate>
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" onClick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_tag" value="2" id="id_select_tag_0" /> Mysql
    </label >
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_tag" value="3" id="id_select_tag_1" /> Disk health
    </label2>       
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!. But is there any default solution without js? I thought it is quite trivial task

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've some weird spaces in your form element and didn't set an action.

Try replace:

`<form class="form-group" action ="" method = "get" novalidate>`

With

`<form class="form-group" action="#" method="get" novalidate>`

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help. I've found out that the issue is caused by  data-toggle="buttons" parameter. If I remove it submit button works but that turned other buttons into checkboxes+buttons which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `data-toggle="buttons"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Change your button's class:
`class="btn btn-success submit"`